# How do I stop my dog from barking when I bring him outside?

Tags: dogs, behavior, vocalizations

Every day we tie our dog up outside because we live in the country, and he likes to get into a lot of mud.

But whenever we bring him outside, he always starts barking like crazy to go back inside. How do I get him to stop barking when I bring him outside?

Comment: How long do you leave him outside for? Is he outside alone? Does he start barking when he's alone, or immediately when you bring him out? Is he barking towards your general location, as in he wants you to acknowledge him, or is he barking at something else, like unapparent noise or passer-byers? Could you add a bit of detail to your question. At this point, we could give advice for any specific situation, so not knowing the situation makes your question **very** broad. Also, providing his age and how long this behavior has been going on for would be helpful.